# React-Facebook-Login and Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth-2.0, react-redux

I'm using `React with Redux` on the client and `Node.js with Express` as an `Rest API` on the server. I've implemented a local login with `passport` but I also wan't to implement social login, such as Facebook login.

I'm using `react-facebook-login` where the user gets authenticated and some information are returned in the response, including AccessToken, Email, Name, ID, etc. I then want to send these information to the server (running on another port) and save the user there to the database (MongoDb). This is how the user schema is structured:

```
const userSchema = Schema({
  local: {
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: String,
    name: String
  },
  facebook: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    email: String,
    name: String
  },
...
```

After a user has been saved to the database I return a JWTtoken to the client with this function:

```
const tokenForUser = (user) => {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  return jwt.encode({ sub: user._id, iat: timestamp }, SECRET);
};
```

The token can then be used to authenticate.

OK, here is the real problem. When creating a Facebook user I first check if the user exists, if not then create him:

```
const facebookSignIn = (model, cb) => {
  User.findOne({ 'facebook.id': model.id }, (err, docs) => {
    if (err) {
      return cb({ 'status': HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        'message': { error: 'Unable to search for an user due to an unknown error' } });
    } else if (docs) {
      return cb(null, { token: tokenForUser(docs) });
    }

    const user = new User({
      facebook: {
        id: model.id,
        token: model.accessToken,
        email: model.email,
        name: model.name
      }
    });

    user.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        if (err.name === VALIDATION_ERROR) {
          return cb({ 'status': HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED,
            'message': { error: Object.keys(err.errors).map(e => `${err.errors[e].message} `) } });
        }
        return cb({ 'status': HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
          'message': { error: 'Unable to save user due to an unknown error' } });
      }

      return cb(null, { token: tokenForUser(user) });
    });
  });
};
```

If a user has been authenticated (exists in the database) then there can be a request sent to the server only containing his/her Facebook ID. Then the user will be allowed to enter the website and will be returned a JWTtoken.

I need to authenticate the accessToken from the user when he/she is authenticated on the server. How can I authenticate the accessToken on the server by bypassing CORS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the user is authenticated he/she needs to send the JWT to the server, no just the fb Id, the jwt can contain an id if you need it for some reason. You should not be able to bypass CORS for security reasons. And you can send the JWT on authorization header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to validate the accessToken with `facebook graph` by sending a GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/me from the server, containing the accessToken.